# Getting TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Tags: python

I am trying to increment a value in my dictionary by 1, but for some reason I keep getting the error 
    TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

I'm a Python noob. Running Python 3.5.6, and I've tried storing the dictionary key as a variable, but it's not working.

```
if message.content.startswith('!iwin'):
    data[str(message.author)]['win'] = data[str(message.author)].get('win') + 1 
   print(data[str(message.author)]['win'])
   win_msg = "Your win has been recorded! You now have"
   +str(data[str(message.author)]['win'])+ " wins!"
```

data.json that I am importing

```
{"User1": {"loss": 0, "win": 0, "hero": [708, 786, 125, 350, 230, 745], "coins": 0}
```

I am importing this with:

```
data = {}
with open('data.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

I want it so that if this gets triggered, the value associated to the key 'win' is incremented by 1.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
In this case, you haven't bothered to provide or trace the values in use.

Comment: The problem is in the value of `message.author`. The error is telling you that it is a dictionary, and you can't cast a dictionary into a string with `str()`. We need  more code to find out the way to get the proper key for `data`, probably `message.author['name']`, or something like that.

Comment: @HugoLuisVillalobosCanto If it's a dictionary, why does the error say `int`? This error message usually happens when you try to concatenate a string and int.

Comment: Are you sure `data.json` says `"win": 0`? This error would happen if it said `"win": "0"`.

Comment: @HugoLuisVillalobosCanto Also, the message says "implicitly". Calling `str()` is an explicit conversion, not implicit. This error would happen if `.get("win")` returns a string, it will complain about trying to add `1` to that.

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error so we can see where it's happening.

Comment: @Barnar, you are right. @aishaq11 you should try `win_msg = "Your win has been recorded! You now have {} wins!".format(data[str(message.author)]['win'])`

Comment: Okay so I think what happened was I messed up on the second line:
`data[str(message.author)]['win'] = data.get(str(message.author)).get(int('win')) + 1` is the proper form. Because now I get another error:
`data[str(message.author)]['win'] = data.get(str(message.author)).get(int('win')) + 1`
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'win'`

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem.

Initially when I coded this out, I had: 
`data[str(message.author)]['win'] = data[str(message.author)].get('win') + 1`

There was bad syntax there, so I think it was getting the wrong value from the dictionary, AKA a string value.

Afterward, when I tried `data[str(message.author)]['win'] = data.get(str(message.author)).get(int('win')) + 1`

It gave me an error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'win'`
I'm still not entirely sure why it gave me that error, because I'm pretty sure 0 is still an int.

Next I tried: `data[str(message.author)]['win'] += 1` and it worked beautifully.
The simplest solution is always the best solution.